Adding a new child component dynamically
I'm playing around with an idea for a react library to help with layout.
In most cases for a full page column layout I'm using flexbox, but there are a couple of edge cases where it doesn't work, so I'm trying to fall back to using floats.
I'm creating a component that takes all the children passed in and uses Children.map to add float: left to each one. That worked fine. Now I want to add a clear: both div at the end and it works, but it's giving me an "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" error. Thoughts?
children = <>
  {
    React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;
      let childProps = child.props;
      const width = childProps.width;
      if (!width) {
        childProps = { ...childProps, width: nonBlankWidthCalculation };
      }
      const childStyle = { ...childProps.style, float: `left` };
      childProps = { ...childProps, style: childStyle };
      child = React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
      return child;
    })
  }
  <div key="clear" style={{ clear: `both` }}></div>
</>;


It fixed it to use jsx instead of React.cloneElement.
children = <>
  {
    React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;
      let childProps = child.props;
      const childStyle = { ...childProps.style, float: `left` };
      const width = childProps.width;
      if (!width) {
        childProps = { ...childProps, width: nonBlankWidthCalculation };
      }
      childProps = { ...childProps, style: childStyle };
      // since we've resolved the width, we can remove grow from child if it exists
      delete childProps.grow;
      return <child.type {...childProps} />;
    })
  }
  <div key="clear" style={{ clear: `both` }}></div>
</>;

